# Facebook SDK 4.0 iOS Native Only App Invites not received by Test User

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-invite

I'm trying to implement App invites from my iOS App.Invites are sent out successfully, but test users never receive anything. This is how i send out invites:

```
 FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] initWithAppLinkURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/xxxxxxxxxxx"]];
content.previewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https:xxxxxx.png"];
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

The App has been approved on Facebook but is still in testing before submitting to the App Store. It is an iOS only app. In testing the App successfully sends out App invites and receives a response in the delegate method

```
-(void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
```

the response is "didComplete = 1 "which confirms this. I have also  tested the App link attached to the Invite to check it works, if the app is not installed Facebook tries to find it on the App store, if it is installed the link opens the app. I've tried using Test users who are not enabled on the app, i've also tried assigning real accounts with tester roles. Neither receive the invite. This is version 1.0 of the app, so its not currently in the app store, therefore it is not possible to set the "iPhone Store ID" setting on the Facebook App settings page. Does the app need to be live in the Apple app store before users receive an invite? I would have thought test users/testers would still receive an invite even if its not live in the Apple App Store?If not, Facebook documentation doesn't seem to mention this anywhere.

I've been researching what might be wrong, but can't seem to sort this out. There are similar questions on Stack overflow, but none that match exactly for this case and SDK version. The solutions suggested in the similar cases don't work for me either. I would simply comment on those existing questions, but i don't have enough reputation points to comment!Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Just found a solution - Looks like you need to put in a live iPhone Store ID into your Facebook App Settings. When i did this the invite was received by 'Test Users' but it is still not received by real accounts that i have assigned as 'Testers'. Not sure why it is still not working for the Testers, but at least i know now that its just because the app is not live and its not a coding issue with the app! This is good enough for me to go ahead with releasing it on the app store without worrying too much! I'll give it a test once its live on the app store.